# Invisible mode on Adium shows as "Away" to ICQ contacts

Tags: instant-messaging, adium

I've installed invisible mode on Adium. Unfortunately instead of seeing me as invisible (i.e. grey sign, "offline" message), my ICQ contacts are seeing the red circle and "away" message.

Is there anything I can configure so that I truly am invisible to my contacts?

Comment: Which service? AIM, ICQ, ...?

Comment: The service is ICQ.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that ICQ has an "invisible" option; if you can see what contacts are online or chat with them, then they will be able to see that you are online.

You could sign out of that account and prevent them from seeing you that way, but I don't think that anything short of that will work.

Comment: Actually, it has in Status. Perhaps, I just have to figure it out myself by trial-and-error method using Edit Status Menu. But still am waiting for tips and help.

Comment: It does have such an option but libpurple doesn't implement it properly - at least there are tons of bug reports and forum entries on that topic.